# what is the equivalent of notify_url?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

what is the equivalent of notify_url in Adaptive payments. Anyone who knows this please i know already return and cancel url my problem is the notify url in adaptive payments.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Developer Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/):

`ipnNotificationUrl`    xs:string (Optional) The URL to which you want all IPN messages for this payment to be sent. Maximum length: 1024 characters